# Norm and Matrice Proof

Tags: matrices, inequality, proof-verification, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show that the following statement is true:

If $||\mathbf a - \theta \mathbf b||^2 - ||\mathbf a||^2 \geq 0$ 
for all $\theta \in [0,1]$, then $\mathbf a^T \mathbf b \le 0$.

Is this how I would go about this??
$$\sqrt{a - \theta b}^2 - \sqrt{a}^2 \geq 0$$

$$a- \theta b - a \geq 0$$

I'm not sure how to get to the right conclusion.

(I'm using the Euclidean Norm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ || a - \theta  b||^2 - || a||^2 
=  || a||^2 + \theta^ 2  || b||^2 - 2\theta a\cdot b - || a||^2 
=  \theta^ 2  || b||^2 - 2\theta a\cdot b
$$

this function of theta is minimum when
$$
\theta = \frac{a\cdot b}{|| b||^2}
$$

If $
a\cdot b > 0
$ this value is in $[0,1]$.

$$
0\le f\left(\frac{a\cdot b}{|| b||^2}\right)
= -\frac {(a\cdot b)^2}{|| b||^2}
$$

This is impossible.

Comment: So you're saying that If $||\mathbf a - \theta \mathbf b||^2 - ||\mathbf a||^2 \geq 0$ 
for all $\theta \in [0,1]$, then $\mathbf a^T \mathbf b \le 0$ is not a true statement?

Comment: I say that if (.... the same thing) then $a\cdot b >0$ is not a true statement

Comment: Ok I see it now. Thanks!